# Vaadin bind LocalDate and RadioButtonGroup

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, bind

How to bind from Vaadin **RadioButtonGroup country** to **Country country** DAO object?  Country is enum and **DateField(vaadin)** to **LocalDate(DAO)**

```
public class Person {

    @Id
    String id;
    LocalDate dateBorn;
    Country country;
```

......

```
public class PersonFormUI extends GridLayout {

    RadioButtonGroup<Country> country;
    DateField dateBorn;
```

........

```
public enum Country {
    EN, DE, IT }
```

with this binding all fields are binded and runs well but how to bind enums and dates withConverter?

```
binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
binder.setBean(personDAO);
```

Comment: What kind of converter do you need to use? Also what Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: whatever will help bind from vaadin fields to java dao object, I use last version 8.3.0 . Vaadin has no dates convertors or enum convertors i see in documentation, or I have to parse enums and dates to string?

Comment: I believe 8.3.1 is the latest, and I also don't think you need any converters nor to parse strings, Vaadin will take care of it. You can find a sample in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If I may add a couple of suggestions before going straight to code:

- If you want a nicely aligned form you can use [`FormLayout`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-formlayout.html)
- I'd suggest using a [`ComboBox`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-combobox.html) instead of [`RadioButtonGroup`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-optiongroups.html) to display the countries, as it uses less space and also allows you to quickly find what you want by typing in it. But if you really want the radio, replace the combo line with `RadioButtonGroup<Country> countries = new RadioButtonGroup<>("Country", DataProvider.ofItems(Country.values()));`

You can find below a sample of binding based on the suggestions above and Vaadin 8.3.1. I don't see the need for any conversions, since the framework will take care of it for you.

The only extra thing I did, was to add an `ItemCaptionGenerator` for the combo to display the full country name instead of the default, which uses the Enum name (same thing can be used with `RadioButtonGroup`).

**Code:**

```java
public class PersonForm extends FormLayout {

    public PersonForm() {
        // form components
        DateField birthDate = new DateField("Birth date");
        ComboBox<Country> countries = new ComboBox<>("Country", Arrays.asList(Country.values()));

        // use full country name instead of ugly Enum name
        countries.setItemCaptionGenerator(Country::getFullName);

        // do not allow the user to select "nothing"
        countries.setEmptySelectionAllowed(false);

        // binder setup
        Binder<Person> userBinder = new Binder<>();

        // birth date binding
        userBinder.forField(birthDate)
                .asRequired("Please provide a birth date")
                .bind(Person::getDateBorn, Person::setDateBorn);

        // country binding
        userBinder.forField(countries)
                .asRequired("Please select the country of residence")
                .bind(Person::getCountry, Person::setCountry);

        // bind to bean with some existing value (eg, loaded from DB for editing)
        userBinder.setBean(new Person(LocalDate.now(), Country.RO));

        // simulate a save action
        Button saveButton = new Button("Save", event -> Notification.show("Saved new user info: " + userBinder.getBean()));

        // add fields to the UI
        addComponents(birthDate, countries, saveButton);
    }

    // beans
    public class Person {
        private LocalDate dateBorn;
        private Country country;

        public Person(LocalDate dateBorn, Country country) {
            this.dateBorn = dateBorn;
            this.country = country;
        }

        public LocalDate getDateBorn() {
            return dateBorn;
        }

        public void setDateBorn(LocalDate dateBorn) {
            this.dateBorn = dateBorn;
        }

        public Country getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(Country country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "dateBorn=" + dateBorn +
                    ", country=" + country +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public enum Country {
        RO("Romania"), DE("Deutschland"), IT("Italy");

        private String fullName;

        Country(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Person editor]

---

You can go even further and disable the button based on the *binder status* (maybe you want to use the same form to add new people where there are no initial values):

```
// disable saving until all required data is available
userBinder.addStatusChangeListener(event -> saveButton.setEnabled(userBinder.isValid()));`
```

**Result:**

[image: Validation]

Comment: im new in vaadin still, but thanks a lot what a quick sample you did, great job thanks a lot you are god :-D I thougt if I use binder.bindInstanceFields(this); for same fields it will automatic bind, some other properties i have to validate with binder.bind thnaks

Comment: I dont want use FormLayout with problems i asked before :-D I use GL with simple switch x,y component add to position I want like my demo https://petmiksoft.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @petmik, You're welcome. If you edit your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085657/vaadin-formlayout-visible) with a quick code sample, we can probably figure out what your issues is with the `FormLayout` as well, but like I said, without having a way to reproduce the issue it's difficult to figure out what is happening.

Comment: ok it is headache i solve it with navigations I learn it few days how it works

Comment: btw great hint with enum string constants I have other enum but with diacritic and I see radiobuttons has setItemCaptionGenerator inside i did tricky fool looping MAN("muž"), WOMAN("žena"), CHILD("dítě");